# Find the limit of this integral $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{n\cos^2x}{1 + n^2x^2}\,dx}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Find the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{n\cos^2x}{1 + n^2x^2}\mathrm{d}x}$$

I know I should start by subsituting in $y = nx$, but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: What are the limits of $y$?  And how do you “know” that the first step is to substitute $y=nx$?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't really want the $y$ in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable $y=nx$ one gets, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{n\cos^2x}{1 + n^2x^2}\:dx=\int\limits_{0}^{n}\frac{\cos^2\frac{y}{n}}{1 + y^2}\:dy=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}1_{[0,n]}(y) \cdot\frac{\cos^2\frac{y}{n}}{1 + y^2}\:dy \to \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1 + y^2}=\frac \pi2
$$ where one may used the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: thank you! what happened to the n in the numerator in the first step?

Comment: @VinnyChase You are welcome. Observe that $y=nx$ gives $ndx=dy$.

Comment: so to use DCT, you let your {$f_n$} = $1_{[0,n]}(y) \cdot\frac{\cos^2\frac{y}{n}}{1 + y^2}$ then they go to the original function $\frac{n\cos^2x}{1 + n^2x^2}$ pointwise on[0,1] and |$f_n$| $\leq$ $\frac{n\cos^2x}{1 + n^2x^2}$ and then you've met all the assumptions?

Comment: You rather write $\displaystyle |f_n(y)|\le \frac{1}{1 + y^2}$, the latter being the dominating function.

Comment: $+1.$ However, I'd write $n\,dx=dy$ rather than $n dx=dy. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I do agree with you. Thanks.